# If my url link contain Unicode characters then it is not redirecting to right destination in internet explorer 9

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, unicode, http-headers

If my url contain unicode characters , then the internet explorer render it to some different charactere and finally does not able to redirect it to correct destination.
I am giving you an example.

my url is like - `http://localhost:2582/Wk/c/दर्शन`

and it will generate url like this - `http://localhost:2582/Wk/c/%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%A1`

But firefox and chrome is working fine.
so what will be reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After search and reading in the internet I got the ans 
It is the way http works - It is a mechanism for encoding information in a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) under certain circumstances. Although it is known as URL encoding it is, in fact, used more generally within the main Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) set.

[Read More](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)
So you just need to decode the url to the origina state.
By using this

```
Uri.UnescapeDataString(urlString);
```

Comment: user352353, can you provide any details?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an encoding issue, what character set do you expect IE to use here ?

Comment: we are using devnagri charter set --  URL is -- http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UA8E0.pdf